# EnumMap raise NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, enum-map

I've got a Enum and an `EnumMap<Parameters, Byte>`.

I put the map into a class to hide the "byte" values. So I have a `set(Parameter, int)` and `set(Parameter, boolean)` method.

```
public enum Parameter {
    BLAH
}


public class Parameters {
    private final Map<Parameter, Byte> parameters = new EnumMap<>(Parameter.class);

    public byte set(Parameter parameter, boolean set) {
        return this.parameters.put(parameter, (byte) (set ? 0x01 : 0x00));
    }

    public byte set(Parameter parameter, int value) {
        return this.parameters.put(parameter, (byte) value);
    }
}
```

When I call any of my methods a NPW will raise which point to `put`! If I made the `parameters` public and call the method dircetly it works.

```
final Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
//parameters.parameters.put(Parameter.BLAH, (byte) 0x00);
parameters.set(Parameter.BLAH, false); // NPE
```

Can anybody explain me the is behaviour to me?

Comment: this should show a compiler error: new EnumMap<>(Parameter.class);

Comment: @StefanBeike: Why would it throw a compation error there? That's perfectly valid code.

Comment: Cannot infer type arguments for EnumMap<> ???

Comment: @StefanBeike: Odd - it's working for me in Java 7...

Comment: @StefanBeike: It's working for me in Java 8 as well... are you sure you've declared an enum called `Parameter`?

Comment: Ahhh damn. I have created a small private class :-)

Comment: You only get that error if you define the `enum` as a `class` by mistake. Another reason why it's easier to help people who provide complete examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the way you're using the return value of [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#put-K-V-), which is documented as:

> the previous value associated with specified key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with the specified key.)

The first time you call the `set` method for any particular key, the return value will be `null` - but you're then unboxing it to `byte`, which will throw the exception you're seeing.

Assuming you *want* to return the previous value, just change the return type to `Byte` for each method.

Comment: hum, you are right. i figured out by my self right after I posted the question.

Comment: @MarcelJaeschke Yeah, that's what everyone says to Jon... ;-)

Comment: @Duncan Lol. That's what everyone says when they post a question so that they have a bunch of people work on it for free whle they take their own sweet time to figure out a solution. ;). Btw people click the upvote button for Jon Skeet just like the way photograpers click away when they see a celeb ;)

Comment: @bot Seriously? So there is not the possibility that I overlooked the boxing?! I'm here for 4 years and only asked a view questions.

Comment: @MarcelJaeschke I am talking about the general public and not you specifically. Both Duncan and me are just playing around. Apologies if it sounded rude. I only meant it as a joke :)